# Telegram-cli list and delete contacts with linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, telegram

I have installed telegram-cli in Ubuntu OS. now i want to list my telegram contacts with telegram-cli via bash script where shows Username + Phone in text or excel file.

How it?